# How to make text with CSS and follow image size

Tags: css, swiper.js

I have some problem with input text to image, i use swiper slider for the image and i create a class to text like this,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 970px) {
  .swiper-slide .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
  }

  .swiper-slide .medsos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }

  .swiper-slide .role {
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
}
```

I made the layout adjust to the size of 971px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 971px)
```

I tested 971px but when I used the size of the cell phone it disappeared, 
did I have to make the layout of each pixel? How do you make the text responsive and the same location from the desktop version to the mobile version?

Comment: Could you provide some more code? use the snippet feature there u can live-test your code inside the question

Comment: @Synoon i have add the url, see what they said section

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 970px) {
  .swiper-slide .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
  }

  .swiper-slide .medsos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }

  .swiper-slide .role {
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 971px) {
 // put the style rules that you want to show in moblie devices
}
```